# Differentiating the integral $h(x) = \int_\limits{0}^{x^2} e^{x+t}dt$

Tags: calculus

I want to solve the following problem: Let $h$ be the funtion defined by $h(x) = \int_\limits{0}^{x^2} e^{x+t}dt$ for all real numbers $x$. Then $h'(1)= ?$.

I know I can integrate $h(x)$, then differentiate and evaluate. However, for practice I was trying to differentiate the whole integral and my procedure gave me a value like: $h'(x) = e^{x+x^2}\cdot 2x$, however this does not give me the right answer which is $3e^2-e$. Does someone know how to do the differentiation of the integral appropriately in this case? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80663/using-ftc1-to-differentiate-a-definite-integral-that-has-a-function-for-a-bound?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

The key is to break up the the exponent.  Recognizing that $e^{x+t}=e^x e^t$ and the fact that $e^x$ is a constant with respect to the integral (so you can pull it out) gives

$h(x)=e^x\int_{0}^{x^2}e^t dt$

The derivative of this can then be found with the product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a fully general formula for this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Answer (score 1):

Just rewrite $$h(x) = e^x \int_0^{x^2} e^t dt$$

In case you're interested in something more challenging, try differentiating this:

$$\int_0^x \frac{ \sin(xt)}{t}dt $$

Hint: First treat integrand as constant and then differentiate with respect to the bound and then treat the bound constant and then differentiate with respect to the integrand. Also, assume we can swap derivative and integral in the latter part.

Observe that the hint applies to $h(x)$ as well.